# How can I gzip a jade template in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, gzip

I would like to gzip my index.pug because apparently it is required so that I can use certain VectorTiles on leaflet.

Here is my server.js

`

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var compression = require('compression');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var $ = require('jquery');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
var session = require('client-sessions');
var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(compression());
app.use(loopback.static(__dirname+'../views'));

app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};
`
```

And this is where I render my '.pug' file

```
`    
 module.exports = function (app) {
   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     //res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
     res.render('index.pug');
   });
 };
`
```

I need to be able to set the header **res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');**, but when I do I get this error: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

I read that the error is caused by the file not being compressed.

This is what I get when I run curl:

    `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    x-download-options: noopen
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    content-length: 26424
    etag: W/"6738-EwRjd2/5wySxOECqPhvhuiz7rTc"
    date: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 22:22:40 GMT
    X-BACKEND: apps-proxy`

**EDIT**

So I think the problem is that compression is compressing it with zlib when I need it to be gzip. Any ideas how to change that?

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for the reply. I thought the compression library is the middleware for it?

Comment: How do you know it isn't already gzipped?  The `app.use(compression);` should make it so that everything is gzipped when sent.

Comment: @zero298 well thats the thing. It should be gzipped but I thought that It would allow me to add that header, but when I do. I get an error that it isn't properly compressed.

Comment: Curl your endpoint without setting the header.  I'm pretty sure that `compression` sets the header for you.  Why do you want to set the header again?

Comment: @zero298 I updated the post to show the results when I curl my endpoint and it doesn't have the header. I need it because it is the only solution I can find for the error I get when trying to render VectorTiles from .pbf's

Comment: This is very strange.  Maybe check [this issue on compression's GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/108).  Maybe you are experiencing something similar.

Comment: @zero298 That sounds like exactly what I am experiencing. They don't offer a solution though.

Comment: Do you think it could have something to do with me using a jade template? Should I just try to render and html?

Comment: When I run it with debug, it is showing that it is compressing some of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have realized that it was in fact gzipping it. I was running the `curl -I --compress` command which just makes a HEAD request. Since there is no body to compress, it will not add the header. Instead use the `curl -is --compress` command so that you can see if it is compressing the body or not.